# Node.js SteamBot not working

Tags: node.js, bots, steam

my Node.js Steam-Bot isnt working. When i try starting him it always gives a Syntax Error:

```
/root/bot/node_modules/steam-tradeoffer-manager/lib/index.js:3
const SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
^^^^^
SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/root/bot/tradebot.js:20:25)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
```

Iam using Debian 8, Node Version 0.12.

Thank you!

Comment: as an aside do yourself a favor and upgrade your nodejs ... current version is v7.4    https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all. Replace `const` with `var`.
Also, you should update your nodeJS version as mentioned in the comments. This is really important.